# how do I use ActionScript 3 / Flash components?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, components, scrollpane

I want to use the ScrollPane component. One tutorial said I go to

```
Window -> Components
```

and click ScrollPane, but there is no components when I go to

```
Window -> Components
```

. I found this:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/components/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fa2.html

If you scroll down in the link above, it mentions that I can import it using ActionScript like so:

```
import fl.containers.ScrollPane;
```

but it gives me an error saying

```
Scene=Szene 1, layer=actions, frame=1, Line 1 Syntax error.
```

I found this later on:
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/617557

and apparently the solution is to "add a ScrollPane to your fla's library"? How do I do this? One of the users on that forum also mentioned

"any AS3 package that begins with fl requires a component either on stage or in the library of that FLA file". How do I put a component of the ScrollPane in the library? Isn't the ScrollPane what I am trying to import?

Note: I am using Flash CS5 and ActionScript 3.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I was working in Adobe Flash CS5 and I needed to change the Flash player version to Flash Player 10 and verify that ActionScript 3 was being used.